# How can I make a simple invoice computation with the use of labels?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code as my computation for the bill.

```
private void UpdateTotalBill()
{
    double vat = 0;
    double TotalPrice = 0;
    long TotalProducts = 0;
    foreach (DataListItem item in dlCartProducts.Items)
    {
        Label PriceLabel = item.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label; // get price 
        TextBox ProductQuantity = item.FindControl("txtProductQuantity") as TextBox; // get quantity
        double ProductPrice = Convert.ToInt64(PriceLabel.Text) * Convert.ToInt64(ProductQuantity.Text); //computation fro product price. price * quantity
        vat = (TotalPrice + ProductPrice) * 0.12; // computation for vat
        Math.Round(vat, 2);
        TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ProductPrice;
        TotalProducts = TotalProducts + Convert.ToInt32(ProductQuantity.Text);

    }
    Label1.Text =Convert.ToString(vat);
    txtTotalPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalPrice + 40 + vat); // add vat + 40 delivery charge to total price
    txtTotalProducts.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalProducts);
}
```

Well what I want to do is to show the computation from the back end to front end with the use of labels. Like for example 1000(product price) x 3(product quantity) + vat(100) + delivery charge(4) = (total)4000. Something like this?

Comment: Can you clarify - what is your exact problem?

Comment: Well then just make combined use of static text and `Label` to print out such a formatted string as output.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev i just wan to show the detailed computation of the query. like the system already computes for it and displays the total product in the textbox. what i want is to show the details of it. like price multipliet by the quantity and so on

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod it is not the problem description, it is description of your goal. But what problem prevents you from doing it? Is something wrong with the code you've posted? And how all this stuff concerned to `asp.net` mentioned in tags? Code looks like winforms one.

Comment: im not experiencing any errors with the code. its working fine. but what i want to know is if there are any tricks or suggestions on how i can attain my goal. thanks @AndyKorneyev

Comment: What are you hoping that this `Math.Round(vat, 2);` line will do?

Comment: hoping that the price for example is 12345.12345 will be 12345.12

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod - Then you need to assign the result to something. It should be something like `vat = Math.Round(vat , 2);`.

Comment: thanks sir! @Enigmativity any idea on how will i implement a simple cmputation method with the use of labels? its somehow like the answer below. thats what i had in mind

Comment: like for example label1.Text will have the value of the product price. then label2.Text will have the quantity and so on?

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod - I've added an answer for you.

Comment: ok ill try this one out. so ill try this code and replace my existing one?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
lblResult.Text=lblPrice.Text+" (ProductPrice) * " +lblProductQuantity.Text + " + (Product Quantity) + "+vat+" (VAT) + " + lblDeliveryCharge.Text + " (Delivery Charge) = "+((Convert.ToDouble(lblPrice.Text)*Convert.ToDouble(lblProductQuantity.Text))+Convert.ToDouble(vat)+Convert.ToDouble(lblDeliveryCharge.Text));
```

Comment: yes something like this. ill try this one out. hey @learningNew, please do still help me regarding the highlight products on my recent query. please

Comment: I have formatted the answer. Its just string concat.

Comment: tried it out but im confused on where will i put the code that starts with "!" on the highlight method

Comment: i get your point on this answer but how will i do it if i have a constant delivery charge value of 40?

Comment: replace lblDeliveryCharge.Text with "40" (with quotes).

Comment: yes im able to do the whole computation. but its only getting one item. i am able to get product price , quantity and result. but when i add another item, it doesnt compute....

Comment: any updates on the highlight method? really need it badly sir. thanks @learningNew

Comment: looks like working at first but then when i remove one product, all of the highlighted products are being unhighlighted? really thank you for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you're performing calculations on monetary values - so you should be using `decimal` and not `double`. The former is for money and the latter for scientific values.

So, start with a delivery value defined:

```
var delivery = 40m;
```

Now compute the values of each item:

```
var items =
(
    from item in dlCartProducts.Items.Cast<DataListItem>()
    let PriceLabel = item.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label
    let ProductQuantity = item.FindControl("txtProductQuantity") as TextBox
    let price = decimal.Parse(PriceLabel)
    let ProductQuantity = decimal.Parse(ProductQuantity)
    let TotalPrice = price * quantity
    let VAT = Math.Round(TotalPrice * 0.12)
    select new
    {
        ProductQuantity,
        TotalPrice,
        VAT,
    }
).ToArray();
```

Now you can easily compute the totals:

```
var totals = new
{
    ProductQuantity = items.Sum(i => i.ProductQuantity),
    TotalPrice = items.Sum(i => i.TotalPrice + i.VAT) + delivery,
    VAT = items.Sum(i => i.VAT)
};
```

Now for the existing labels:

```
Label1.Text = totals.VAT.ToString();
txtTotalPrice.Text = totals.TotalPrice.ToString();
txtTotalProducts.Text = totals.ProductQuantity.ToString();
```

And finally, the label showing the calculation:

```
lblResult.Text = String.Format(
    "{0}(product price) x {1}(product quantity) "
        + "+ vat({2}) + delivery charge({3}) = (total){4}",
    (totals.TotalPrice - delivery - totals.VAT) / totals.ProductQuantity,
    totals.ProductQuantity,
    totals.VAT,
    delivery,
    totals.TotalPrice);
```